Google Place Autocomplete Widget Suggestions Items not clickable by mouse
I am experiencing an issue with selecting items in the suggestion dropdown of Google's autocomplete: when I click on them with the mouse, the item is not selected. The only peculiarity is that the autocomplete is placed in a Bootstrap 5 modal window.
I have tried modifying the CSS and adding JS controls, but I haven't been able to achieve any results.
Does anyone know the reason for this? Thank you.
jsfiddle


$(document).ready(function (e) {
  function setMapsHeight() {
    $("#map_content").css(
      "height",
      $("#googleMapsOnModal .modal-body").height()
    );
    $("#pan").css("height", $("#googleMapsOnModal .modal-body").height());
  }
  $("#googleMapsOnModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    const position = { lat: 40.73061, lng: -73.935242 };
    initMap("params", position);
    setMapsHeight();
  });
  $(window).resize(() => {
    setMapsHeight();
  });
});

let map;
let marker;
let infoWindow;

async function initMap(a, position) {
  const [{ Map }, { InfoWindow }] = await Promise.all([
    google.maps.importLibrary("maps"),
    google.maps.importLibrary("places"),
  ]);

  const { AdvancedMarkerElement, PinElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary(
    "marker"
  );

  // Short namespaces can be used.
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map_content"), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: position,
    mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID",
    mapTypeControl: false,
  });

  function getCoord() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    console.log(center);
    var lat = center.lat();
    var lng = center.lng();
    console.log(lat + "," + lng);
  }

  const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById("pano"),
    {
      position: position,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10,
      },
    }
  );

  map.setStreetView(panorama);

  const placeAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.PlaceAutocompleteElement({
    componentRestrictions: { country: ["us"] },
    types: ["establishment"],
  });

  placeAutocomplete.id = "place-autocomplete-input";

  const card = document.getElementById("place-autocomplete-card");
  card.appendChild(placeAutocomplete);
  marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

  $("gmp-place-autocomplete#place-autocomplete-input");
  placeAutocomplete.addEventListener("gmp-placeselect", async ({ place }) => {
    await place.fetchFields({
      fields: ["displayName", "formattedAddress", "location"],
    });
    if (place.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }
    let content =
      '<div id="infowindow-content">' +
      '<span id="place-displayname" class="title">' +
      place.displayName +
      "</span><br />" +
      '<span id="place-address">' +
      place.formattedAddress +
      "</span>" +
      "</div>";
    updateInfoWindow(content, place.location);
    marker.position = place.location;
  });

  // Helper function to create an info window.
  function updateInfoWindow(content, center) {
    panorama.setPosition(center);
    map.setCenter(center);
  }
}
window.initMap = initMap;
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

#map,
#pano {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (g => { var h, a, k, p = "The Google Maps JavaScript API", c = "google", l = "importLibrary", q = "__ib__", m = document, b = window; b = b[c] || (b[c] = {}); var d = b.maps || (b.maps = {}), r = new Set, e = new URLSearchParams, u = () => h || (h = new Promise(async (f, n) => { await (a = m.createElement("script")); e.set("libraries", [...r] + ""); for (k in g) e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, t => "_" + t[0].toLowerCase()), g[k]); e.set("callback", c + ".maps." + q); a.src = `https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?` + e; d[q] = f; a.onerror = () => h = n(Error(p + " could not load.")); a.nonce = m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce || ""; m.head.append(a) })); d[l] ? console.warn(p + " only loads once. Ignoring:", g) : d[l] = (f, ...n) => r.add(f) && u().then(() => d[l](f, ...n)) })
    ({ key: "AIzaSyAq-lpD3yLUEmAdhrgzyJMyTIVDQQJKLe4", v: "beta" });
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#googleMapsOnModal">
  open map
</button>

<!-- Full screen modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="googleMapsOnModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="googleMapsOnModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="googleMapsOnModal">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body ui-front">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-9 row">
              <div class="col-6" id="map_content"></div>
              <div class="col-6" id="pano"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 ms-auto" id="details">
              <div class="col-12 mb-2">
                <div id="custom-search-input">
                  <div class="place-autocomplete-card" id="place-autocomplete-card" style="pointer-events:all"> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='col-12' id='details_sview'></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I tried to modify the behavior through every possible attempt with jQuery, but I couldn't find a solution.
