Google Places (new) Autocomplete not working in Bootstrap 5 Modal
I have a Bootstrap 5 modal which I'd like to use to capture an address. The javascript to initialise the Autocomplete element is below; the autocomplete is correctly added to the modal, but the gmp-placeselect event doesn't fire when an option from the list is clicked. The same code works just fine if the element is on the page, just not in the modal.
There are no console errors.

I've moved it to the main page (success - event fires)
Thought it might be something in Bootstrap causing the issue, so tried swapping it for a native dialog (same result - doesn't work)

So there's something about it being in a modal it just doesn't like.


async function initAutocomplete() {

  const [{ Map }] = await Promise.all([google.maps.importLibrary("places")]);

  //modal
  const placeAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.PlaceAutocompleteElement();
  document
    .getElementById("google-address-autocomplete")
    .appendChild(placeAutocomplete);
  placeAutocomplete.addEventListener("gmp-placeselect", async ({ place }) => {
    await place.fetchFields({
      fields: ["addressComponents"]
    });
    const data = place.toJSON();
    console.log(data);
  });
  
  // page
  const placeAutocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.PlaceAutocompleteElement();
  document
    .getElementById("google-autocomplete-page")
    .appendChild(placeAutocomplete2);
  placeAutocomplete2.addEventListener("gmp-placeselect", async ({ place }) => {
    await place.fetchFields({
      fields: ["addressComponents"]
    });
    const data = place.toJSON();
    console.log(data);
  });
}

initAutocomplete();
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="body" class="container-fluid ps-0 pe-0">
  <div class="container-fluid booking">
    <div class="row mt-3 booking__inputs">
      <customer-details class="col-12">
        <div class="row align-items-end">
          <h4>Modal</h4>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
            <label for="group_id" class="form-label">Address</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="current_address" readonly>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addressModal" id="edit-address">Address</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <h4>Page based</h4>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
            <label class="form-label">Lookup address</label>
            <div id="google-autocomplete-page"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </customer-details>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal fade" data-bs-keyboard="false" id="addressModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="address detail" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5">Address</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 mt-2">
                <label class="form-label">Search for address:</label>
                <div id="google-address-autocomplete"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 mt-2">
                <label for="address1" class="form-label">Address 1</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address1" id="address1" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 mt-2">
                <label for="address2" class="form-label">Address 2</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address2" id="address2" value="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 mt-2">
                <label for="city" class="form-label">City</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" value="" required="">
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 mt-2">
                <label for="postcode" class="form-label">Postcode</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="" required="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-address" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  (g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})({
    key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk",
    v: "beta",
  });
</script>  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0pUGZvbkm6XF6gxjEnlmuGrJXVbNuzT9qBBavbLwCsOGabYfZo0T0to5eqruptLy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. This includes how you are loading the API, the version of Bootstrap you are using, how/where/when you are calling the initAddressAutocomplete() method, etc. etc.

Here's a pen with the (non) working example: https://codepen.io/verdant-spark/pen/ExqKgMb

You are not alone - https://stackoverflow.com/q/78923705/1238965 to me it looks like a bug with Bootstrap modal, maybe a z-index issue? That said I can't seem to be able to adjust the .dropdown z-index with CSS, even with !important rule.

I would suggest you open a new bug in the issue tracker providing your codepen as a reproducible example (you can also link to this question for reference). Note the new autocomplete is still in "preview" so bugs like that can happen.

I have updated your question with a runnable code snippet which uses Google's recommended way of loading the API, removed some unnecessary stuff and replaced your API key with a test key from Google which works here.

Thanks for that. I've ended up getting rid of the modal for now and just put it on the main page, which is fine but not ideal. I'll get round to reporting this in the meantime.
